# Ajax image uploading restrict rest of the form fields using single form

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I want to upload an image using ajax, i have some other fields with some sort of validation that restricts form to submit until they are correctly filled,
But, I have an issue here, whenever i try to upload image, all the fields prompts error,

```
$('#my_thumbnail').on('change', function() {
    $('#my_form').trigger('submit');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?=site_url('admin/uploadLogo')?>",
            success: function(data){

            }
     });
    return false;
});
```

How do i prevent my rest of the form fields to submit while uploading image using ajax without using another form.

Answer (score 0):

You are triggering submit however that's not necessary. If you don't do that, the other fields will not be checked. Because you are using onChange the POST will still fire without the submit trigger.

Comment: I know this is not your question, but is your url correct? Using the short echo tag, I believe you still have to use a semicolon at the end of the statement.